# What is the best way to send/receive a file to a SFTP server in .NET?

Tags: .net, sftp

I am looking to connect to a SFTP server and both push and pull a file.  Initial searches didn't turn up any straightforward "built in" support in .NET, so I may have to buy a third-party library.  For authentication, I want to use Public Key Authentication to avoid having to manage periodic password resets, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, only ftp is built in.  We use SCP to do the file transfers, which may or may not work for you.  We simply shell out and use putty's pscp.  They also have a sftp client you could use.

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746828/sftp-with-net-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

SharpSSH supports SFTP and has a friendly BSD license.

http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

Here is an overview of some other options:

http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftpcompare.php